# How to pass the specific object my form is editing into django?

Tags: django

If I have multiple objects of the same database model displayed on my page, and I want to have an edit button for each of them that allows you to edit the data of said object, how could I pass the data of which one I'm editing to my view so I could edit the fields of that specific database entry.

Right now I have only one form

```
<form method="POST" action="." id="projectForm">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 formheader">Edit Assumption</legend>
                {{ form }}
            <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                <button type="submit" class="createbutton" name="editassumptionformbutton">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I can make the onclick trigger the display of the form like this:

```
<a onclick="toggleVisibilityEdit()">Edit</a>
```

(which is a javascript function that displays the form)

These are my model entries that are being listed:

```
{% for assumption in assumptions reversed %}
        <div class="card existingcard assumption">
            <h2>{{ assumption }}</h2>
            <div class="assumptionbtns">
                <a onclick="toggleVisibilityEdit()">Edit</a>
                <a href="{% url 'problemdashboard:dashboard-assumption' project.pk need.pk assumption.id%}">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

But I have no idea how to tell the view which of the objects I'm currently editing, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

While listing your models, add their Ids in the edit Url. So when you click on any item, its ID will automatically be passed

Comment: okay, I understand the point, but could you please give me a quick example? I'm not quite sure how to do that..

Comment: Please post your code where you are listing model objects